# 2 User Logins Required for Amazon Purchase

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, login-with-amazon

I am trying to develop a web based application in which the user will login to a website members area with 'Login with Amazon' and then he will be redirected to a specific chosen product page at Amazon.

The problem I am observing is that if the user is NOT logged-in to amazon.com prior to the 'Login with Amazon', then the user will need to enter his credentials on the 'Login with Amazon' authentication page, and also at amazon.com if he wishes to purchase the product - This is extremely weird to me and will probably reduce significantly the conversion rate...

Is there a way in the 'Login with Amazon' API to login the user also to amazon.com when the 'Login with Amazon' takes place?

If not, any other solution anyone can think of to avoid 2 consecutive logics of the user?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: when the customer uses Login with Amazon, there is a "keep me signed in" box they can check that could reduce the number of times they have to login. But *they* have to check it. You can't do it for them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Yiddishninja - Appreciate it... What if I choose in the "Login with Amazon" SDK, NOT to use the pop-up option but instead to open in a new windows the "Login with Amazon" page - Will this solve this issue if I then I redirect the user to the product page at amazon.com after the "Login with Amazon"?

Comment: They're just two ways of opening the same form. If you open the page instead of the pop-up, you'll get the results back in a URL fragment(#) instead of a query string(?). How cookies are handled shouldn't be changed.